# Can colored text be applied to Parse push notifications?

Tags: ios

Can various colored text be implemented in Parse IOS push notifications? I'm not concerned about font size or shape but only making the letters different colors. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, a Push notification can only contain a string. A string does not contain any markup.